# Can't see images in mails I compose

Tags: macos, mail.app, graphics, attachments

When I attach an image in a mail, I can throw it anywhere, inline, but it shows up as an image icon rather than actually showing the image:

> [image: mail screenshot]

Any way I can fix this? It also doesn't allow me to make a signature with images.

Comment: Try drag and drop. What are the formats in question ?

Comment: Regular old JPEG. Drag and drop is what i do. I can literally reply to a mail with images in them and see the images, but if i try to copy the text, i see them as icons again, so it's really really only on my end.

Answer (score 1):

To make a signature with images go to Preferences under the Mail menu and click on signatures. You should get a panel that looks like the image below. In the area on the right, right-click and select Import Image. You can select the image you want in your signature.

You can also open an image you want to display. Select all and copy the image. You can then go to the panel shown below and paste into the area on the right.

To solve your problem about images not appearing you can try, instead of loading image into your message, the same method as above. Open the image and copy it, then paste it into your email.

[image]

Comment: I still get the icon in that case, not the image.

Comment: Did you have any luck getting an image in your signature?

Comment: No, i cannot get any image in anything i make. Not in new emails, not in sig. Even though it works fine in mails i receive. In the ones i make, they are there, but as an icon to the image, not as the actual image.